# Save a SharePoint 2013 workflow as template using code behind

Tags: workflow, powershell, client-object-model

We have around 100 SharePoint 2013 workflows in our Farm. We need to save these workflows. It is tedious to manually open Sites in Designer and go to each workflow and store it as a template. Is there a Powershell Script or C# code to achieve this?

Comment: Is this a list workflow or reusable workflow?

Comment: they are all list workflows @SaMoIPP

Comment: REview this link for packaging wsp files.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608051(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Hi Shishirchandra Prasad. I've got the same problem and was wondering if you've managed to find a solution yet?